# How to do live reload with Rails 4 and Ruby 2.0 app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, erb

I want to see live changes in browser if I edit .scss or .erb file in text Editor in Rails 4 + Ruby 2.0 project.

I tried Guard and Guard-live-reload, but it's throwing the following error.

```
22:58:04 - ERROR - Could not load 'guard/rspec' or find class Guard::Rspec
22:58:04 - ERROR - /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:100:in `require'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:100:in `plugin_class'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `block in guard'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `each'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `guard'
> [#] /home/jitendra/milaap-webapp/Guardfile:4:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `instance_eval'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:148:in `evaluate_guardfile'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:64:in `setup'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:107:in `start'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/guard:23:in `load'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
> [#] /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
22:58:04 - ERROR - Invalid Guardfile, original error is:
> [#] undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass
/home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/plugin_util.rb:57:in `initialize_plugin': undefined method `superclass' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard.rb:167:in `add_plugin'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:174:in `block in guard'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `each'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/dsl.rb:173:in `guard'
    from /home/jitendra/milaap-webapp/Guardfile:4:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `instance_eval'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:97:in `_instance_eval_guardfile'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/guardfile/evaluator.rb:37:in `evaluate_guardfile'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:148:in `evaluate_guardfile'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/setuper.rb:64:in `setup'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/commander.rb:24:in `start'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/lib/guard/cli.rb:107:in `start'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor.rb:359:in `dispatch'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/thor-0.19.1/lib/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/gems/guard-2.6.1/bin/guard:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/guard:23:in `load'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/guard:23:in `<main>'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/jitendra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is how i work with livereload:

**1.)** Get the [gem](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload)

In your Gemfile:

```
group :development do
  gem 'guard-livereload', require: false
end
```

**2.)** `guard init livereload`, Which will generate a `Guardfile` at the root of your App.

**3.)** Opening your Guardfile it should look like this (Just the Guard-Livereload, if you run other guard plugins make sure they're below the livereload.)

```
guard 'livereload' do
  watch(%r{app/views/.+\.(erb)$})
  watch(%r{app/helpers/.+\.rb})
  watch(%r{public/.+\.(css|js|html)})
  watch(%r{config/locales/.+\.yml})
  watch(%r{(app|vendor)(/assets/\w+/(.+\.(css|js|html|png|jpg))).*}) { |m| "/assets/#{m[3]}" }
end
```

**4.)** Get the Livereload Chrome App from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei?hl=en)

**5.)** Restart your server and open a separate tab and type-> `guard`

**6.)** In your Browser push the livereload button and it should link it (Browser Connected in the Guard Tab)

I wrote it extensively for other's which may stumble upon the same question. For your specific case read **#3**. Open your guardfile and make sure livereload is called first.

> Go watch the [Railscast #264 Guard](http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard)

When working with SSL, livereload doesn't like that quite well.

[Rack-Livereload](https://github.com/johnbintz/rack-livereload) is a neat little gem which you can add to your project to get around the SSL problems. The gem inserts a piece or Rack middleware and basically connects to the livereload app to serve up the javascript through the existing (and SSL enabled) Rails server.

Comment: 23:40:12 - INFO - LiveReload is waiting for a browser to connect.

Comment: Great, push the Livereload button on your browser.

Comment: ok this is output after i made change in .erb file http://pastebin.com/SeLfx7qr

also page didn't refresh

Comment: Can you please provide your Guardfile ?

Comment: Try replacing it with [this one](https://gist.github.com/Theminijohn/155cd2ffe67b85d84e4d) and add later the capybara and turnib

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57612/discussion-between-jitendra-vyas-and-the-mini-john).

Comment: For it to reload when I edit scss files, I had to add `scss` to the list of file types to watch in my guardfile: `(scss|css|js|html|png|jpg)`

Comment: the point 5. is important, and all the `guard` call on my machine need to be `bundle exec guard`

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/railsjazz/rails_live_reload which could be used in Rails app.

With it you can reload only rendered pages if you making edits in them, or when you are changing locale files, or CSS, etc.